# Loading CSV file Data into Mysql using Rubygems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Trying to insert the data into DB from a csv file using ruby programming.
I am fresher to scripting in ruby because of this facing issue.

the data in CSV file is as follows:

```
12,prakash,nair,kerala,india
13,koteswarreddy,aula,andhra pradesh,india
14,kush,gambhir,punjab,india
15,james,arnold,NY,USA
```

kindly, suggest me to load this data into the data base Employee using Ruby.

```
require 'csv'
load 'dbconnection.rb'
require 'activerecord'

class Employee<ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

in the **Employee** which i need to load the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed as follows

```
require 'csv'    

csv_text = File.read(/path/to/file)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => false)
csv.each do |row|
  Employee.create!(row)
end
```

Comment: print `row` you will understand what data you are getting. You can write code accordingly. I mentioned model as I saw `ruby-on-rails` tag.

Comment: sir just now i updated the requirement kindly check it

Comment: `ModelCsv` was a placeholder name. I replaced it with `Employee`. Check the edit

Comment: thanks @Sivam, its working but issue is 

csv.each do |row|
  Employee.create!(
    **_:id => row['id'],_**
    :fname => row['fname'],
    :lname => row['lname'],
    :state => ['state'],
    :country => ['country']
    )   
end

Error is:     ** can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)**

Comment: @MODIRANGANAYAKULU if its working please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and ask a fresh question if you have further doubts.